# Searching the string and getting the row and column value

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

How to search the particular string in the excel sheet and getting the row and column  value of that  particular  string in the excel sheet using `xlrd` in python? Can any one help me please?

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("1234.xls")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('firstpage')
```

only this much i tried

Comment: You can add your code that you tried to the question, to make it more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for , Here you go,

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook(workbookName)
for sheet in book.sheets():
    for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(rowidx)
        for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell.value == "particularString" :
                print sheet.name
                print colidx
                print rowidx
```

best,

Comment: dood you dont have to call me sir. I am your friend enjoy. Kindly Upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Say you're searching for a string `s`:

```
for row in range(sh.nrows):
    for column in range(sh.ncols):
        if s == sh.cell(row, column).value:  
            return (row, column)
```

Comment: If my condition `if cell.value == "particularString" :` evaluates to be true, then I want to pick the value in the cell next to it. How to do that?